# Get Top 5 For Each Metric For Each Month For Each Item

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble creating the query to break my now daily, table into a top monthly.

I have a table with the following structure (note the headers are actually all caps):

```
Start_Date | Month| Item | Location | ... | Quantity | Sales | 
-----------|------|------|----------|-----|----------|-------|
8/6/19     |  08  |   A  |    USE   | ... |          |       |
8/6/19     |  08  |   B  |    USE   | ... |          |       |
8/6/19     |  08  |   C  |    USW   | ... |          |       |
8/6/19     |  08  |   D  |    USW   | ... |          |       |
8/5/19     |  08  |   A  |    USE   | ... |          |       |
8/5/19     |  08  |   B  |    USE   | ... |          |       |
8/5/19     |  08  |   C  |    USW   | ... |          |       |
8/5/19     |  08  |   D  |    USW   | ... |          |       |
.....
7/1/19     |  07  |   D  |    USW   | ... |          |       |
```

Every date has the metrics above, there's 4 rows per day due to the 4 different items, which I want -- comparing by item. My goal is to now break this out to a monthly table, with the goal of taking the top 5 in each category (Quantity, Sales, etc.) for that month and getting the AVG of that.

```
Example: Item A
8/6/19: Quantity = 500 | Sales = 100
8/5/19: Quantity = 478 | Sales = 130
8/4/19: Quantity = 366 | Sales = 113
8/3/19: Quantity = 678 | Sales = 90
8/2/19: Quantity = 594 | Sales = 92
8/1/19: Quantity = 500 | Sales = 105
```

Note: There's data for the other items B, C and D respectively.

My goal was to take the top 5 for each category and present that at the monthly level:

Results:

```
| Month| Item | Location | ... | Quantity | Sales | 
|------|------|----------|-----|----------|-------|
|  08  |   A  |    USE   | ... |    550   |  108  |
|  08  |   B  |    USE   | ... |          |       |
|  08  |   C  |    USW   | ... |          |       |
|  08  |   D  |    USW   | ... |          |       |
|  07  |   A  |    USE   | ... |          |       |
|  07  |   B  |    USE   | ... |          |       |
|  07  |   C  |    USW   | ... |          |       |
|  07  |   D  |    USW   | ... |          |       |
```

Quantity = 550 was taken from 8/1 -> 8/6 Quantity adding the top 5 (1, 2, 3, 5, 6) and dividing by 5 (AVG of top 5). Then Sales was 1, 2, 4, 5, 6.
So obviously I need to query each category (Quantity, Sales, etc.) separately and then UNION the results together. I'm just struggling with how to even get the TOP 5 of a specific category.

I've done some searching on Stack and Google for how to obtain the Top5 in a query. I see some threads that suggest you can actually use `TOP(5)` which doesn't work for me. `LIMIT 5` only limits the results to 5, and I'm unable to use LIMIT in a subquery w/ the most recent version of SQL. Ordering and using a simple statement like "number <= 5" won't work since the months are different in the later rows of the dataset... I'm able to get the AVG for all the data for a specific month by simply just SELECTing the AVG() and GROUPing by ITEM but I want to project a top 5/10 which I've been unable to figure out.

Thanks for your assistance. I could throw out some of the queries I've tried but none are even close as I've been trying to use LIMIT.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select month, item,
       avg(case when seqnum_q <= 5 then quantity end) as quantity_top5,
       avg(case when seqnum_s <= 5 then sales end) as sales_top5
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by item, month order by quantity desc) as seqnum_q,
             row_number() over (partition by item, month order by sales desc) as seqnum_s
      from t
     ) t
group by month, item;
```

Note:  Using `month` without `year` is discomfiting.  Either `year` should be included in the logic, or you should be clear that the data is only for one year.

Comment: I get "Unknown column 'seqnum' in 'field list'" When I run this code